# Integrability of random variable- theoretic aspect

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

in some topics (for example in martingale theory, strong law of large numbers), we have to check integrability of a given random variable $X$, i.e. $E|X|<\infty$.
Okay, so assume that I have some random variable $X$ and I know only that $EX=3$. I cant compute $E|X|$, but do I need it to confirm integrability? Random variable is integrable if $EX^+$ and $EX^-$ are finite and I think that until now we know only that $EX^+-EX^-=3$ and I think that it implies that integrability properties mentioned above, because we cant get the $3$ number as a difference of two infinities. Or maybe we can?

Comment: It depends what you mean by $E[X]$. If it is defined by the Lebesgue integral as is customary in probability theory then you are right that $E[|X|]$ must be some finite number and the theorems you know about this go through. If instead $E[X]$ is defined by some improper Riemann integral of $x f(x)$ for a density function $f$, then $E[|X|]$ may still not be finite and in this situation some of the central theorems of probability theory such as the laws of large numbers do not hold. The same may occur if $E[X]$ is defined as a sum of $n f(n)$ for a PMF $f$.

Comment: As a concrete example, it is instructive to see what actually happens when you take sample means from the standard Cauchy distribution; in Matlab you can do u=rand(1e6,1);x=tan(pi*(u-1/2));plot(cumsum(x)./(1:1e6)) to see the failure of the strong law of large numbers. This is despite the fact that in the PV sense the standard Cauchy distribution has mean zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we say $X$ must be integrable we mean that $E[X]$ exists and is finite.

So consider the four cases:

1.) $E[X^+] < \infty$ and $E[X^-]<\infty \Rightarrow E[X]<\infty$ AND $E|X|<\infty$

2.) $E[X^+] = \infty$ and $E[X^-]=\infty\Rightarrow E[X]$ d.n.e AND $E|X| = \infty$

3.) $E[X^+] < \infty$ and $E[X^-]=\infty\Rightarrow E[X]=-\infty$ AND $E|X| = \infty$

4.) $E[X^+] = \infty$ and $E[X^-]<\infty\Rightarrow E[X]=\infty$ AND $E|X| = \infty$

Noting that $E[X] = E[X^+]-E[X^-]$ and $E|X| = E[X^+]+E[X^-]$.

So when you consider $E|X|$ you narrow checking X being integrable down to whether $E|X|$ is infinite or not.  This alongside the non-negativity of $E|X|$ is why this definition is used as it's convenient.

Since you know E[X] = 3 you know it is integrable and that it integrates to 3.